Htaccess for protecting gravity forms uploads
I have the following code to make sure that the gravity forms directory in the uploads folder and it's contents cannot be accessed by non-logged in users.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

# Ensure that requests to wp-login.php are not redirected
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/wp-login.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [L]

# Ensure that requests to wp-admin are not redirected
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/wp-admin$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [L]

# Check if the request is within the gravity_forms directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/wp-content/uploads/gravity_forms/ [NC]

# Check if the user is not logged in
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*wordpress_logged_in.*$ [NC]

# Redirect to login page if not logged in
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /wp-login.php [R=302,L]
</IfModule>

howevever, it's not fully working. An example would be this link:
https://www.examplesite.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/gravity_forms/2-8ae1e63a5d3ff208ec0cafb57fd3d365/2023/10/nung-854230.pdf?gv-iframe=true
The above link is not redirecting to the login page when viewed as a guest. But when you try:
https://www.examplesite.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/gravity_forms/2-8ae1e63a5d3ff208ec0cafb57fd3d365/2023/10/ It's redirecting.
So somehow the filenames are not being  restricted and redirected. Can anyone let me know where I'm going wrong?

just checking the cookie is easily bypassable. to filter the access, you can deny the access to the directory and make a script which test the capability of the connected user before to download the file.

Apart from that: the condition you are using matches both requested URLs, there is no reason why the redirection should not get applied. If it is not in your case then some other factor comes into play here. I could imagine that cookie still existing for a guest user, only that it is not valid any more. You will have to debug that which we cannot do for you. Read about rewrite logging in the documentation of the rewriting module.

Where did you put this, is this in the .htaccess on the root level, or did you put it into /wp-content/, /wp-content/uploads/, or /wp-content/uploads/gravity_forms/? If it is on the root level - then the default WP rewriting is missing in what you have shown us. Please show the full thing then, so that we can see this in context, and check if something else might interfere.
